# RegisterStartupScript is not working in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

J have problem with ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript on C#. My code not working 
I have ASP.NET :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
    <script>
        function Test() {
            alert("a");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

And behind code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Test1", "Test();", true);
        }
    }
}
```

I have try 
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`
but them useless

Please help me :( Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're not use any event handler to execute the `Test()` function. Try use an event handler, e.g. `window.onload = Test();`

Comment: see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2